# hostname doesn't get updated in kubectl get nodes command after hostname change

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I changed the hostname on one of the nodes and ended up in this when I issue a kubectl get nodes. How can I update this

```
[root@grs-testkubemaster01 ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                                 STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
abc-testkubemaster01                 Ready      master    22h       v1.10.2
abc-testkubemaster02                 Ready      <none>    19h       v1.10.2
abc-testkubenode01                   Ready      <none>    56m       v1.10.2
abc-testkubenode01.xyz.local         NotReady   <none>    1h        v1.10.2
abc-testkubenode02                   Ready      <none>    19h       v1.10.2
[root@grs-testkubemaster01 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have list out the nodes

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Now you can select specific node and edit **updatable** field in the node resources file. 
for examples

```
kubectl edit nodes abc-testkubemaster01
```

Comment: abc-testkubenode01.xyz.local  and abc-testkubenode01 are the same node. I edited the /etc/hosts on abc-testkubenode01 from abc-testkubenode01.xyz.local to abc-testkubenode01. So I expect to see only one when I do kubectl get nodes, but somehow it shows 2 nodes

Comment: if you could try to edit the host name from above command what result you will get ? It will be interesting if we still get 2 nodes. As I understand its responsibility of kubelet to provide the facts of nodes to the api-server.

Comment: It won't let me edit I get this 
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
# nodes "abc-testkubenode01.xyx.local" was not valid:
# * []: Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity (or configSource, if the DynamicKubeletConfig feature gate is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following actions on the master:

```
kubectl delete node abc-testkubenode01.xyz.local
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

On the worker change your hostname, then reset the kubelet by resetting kubeadm

```
kubeadm reset
```

Then take the output of the join command from the master and paste it into the worker